# Where is the install location for react-native-debugger?

Tags: windows, react-native, react-native-debugger

Currently if I want to use the tool I need to re-run the setup every time

I tried the obvious methods of searching in the start menu, and looking at the setup documentation as well as Google searching. Can't locate it in my program files or in my documents. (I'm using Windows)

I also put in an issue so that in future it can be less of a hassle to find for posterity: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/533

Answer (score 5):

Search on this location.

> %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\react-native-debugger.exe

By default, it does not install in program files so you won't be able to find it from the start menu in windows. One workaround is mentioned by the user on this GitHub issue [#360](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/360) by creating a shortcut in program files, it works. You can also create a desktop shortcut.